# Can't compile dgruyter and caption packages

Tags: templates

I’m having trouble combining the dgruyter and caption packages.

The following code does not run with the dgruyter package (see my comments).

```
\documentclass[USenglish]{article}



\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[small]{dgruyter} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

\usepackage{microtype}



\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{subfigure}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{epsfig}

\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}[2007/12/23]

\usepackage{lscape}

\newcommand{\bunderline}[2][4]{\underline{#2\mkern-#1mu}\mkern#1mu}

\newcommand{\boverline}[2][4]{\overline{#2\mkern-#1mu}\mkern#1mu}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}





\begin{document}



  \author{...} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

 \runningauthor{...} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \affil{....} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \title{...} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \runningtitle{...} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \abstract{...} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \classification[JEL classification]{J24,J22,J44,J13} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \received{...} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \accepted{...} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \journalname{...} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \journalyear{...} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \journalvolume{..} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \journalissue{..} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \startpage{1} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \aop % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS

  \DOI{...} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS



\maketitle % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS



\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}

\caption{A simple longtable example} \label{tab:stat} \\

% %\\

\hline

\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\

\hline

\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}%

{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\

\hline

\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\

\hline

\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\

\endfoot

\hline

\endlastfoot

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\

1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\

\end{longtable}





\end{document}
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't have the `dgruyter` package in my TeX distribution. Where did you get it from? Can you give us the link so we can test, please?

Comment: Why do you have so many blank lines in your code? Is there a special reason to write the code in this way? You know that blank lines have a special meaning: start new paragraph?

Comment: Hi, all suggestions are welcomed, thank you very much. Here you can find all the files that were given to me https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M58oZsWLdChsGWE-UV5R7Mnbs0zzum6z

Comment: Also, the blank lines are an error from the copy & paste. Please ignore them in my main files I dont have any blank lines.

Comment: I think you should write a bug report to the maintainer of that package!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example can be reduced to

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter} % ONLY WORKS IF I COMMENT THIS
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{A simple longtable example} \label{tab:stat} \\
A & B & C & D \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

which leads to the error message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@preamble ...skip 1sp\d@llarbegin \@tablefont 
                                               \ignorespaces \@sharp \uns...

\LT@mcol ...\def \@sharp {#3}\@arstrut \@preamble 
                                                  \null \ignorespaces 
...
l.7 \caption{A simple longtable example}
                                         \label{tab:stat} \\
```

So in fact this is an incompatibility between `dgruyter` and `longtable`.

(The `dgruyter` package was taken from https://www.degruyter.com/dg/page/production-for-authors )

Addendum: The definition of `\@classz` inside `dgruyter.sty` uses `\@tablefont` but this macro isn't defined inside a `longtable`. For `supertabular` there is a patch inside `dgruyter.sty` but there is one missing for `longtable`.

So to make this short: `dgruyter` isn't adapted to the `longtable` package (yet), so use `supertabular` instead. In parallel you could request the adaption to `longtable` from the De Gruyter publisher.

Comment: The package also does `\p@=1bp`, which is likely to break many constructs.

Comment: From dgruyter guide (...table format, etc.) will be carried out in the production department i.e it iuses the supplied tablefont etc.